# Firestore dependency error flutter

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, flutter

I have this app that is working perfectly. Now i need to add firestore functionality and it fails to build.
Console error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Phone in debug mode...
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 
'implementation' instead.
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use 
registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use 
registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use 
registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task 
':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- 
debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 3s
Gradle build failed: 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

The error comes after adding the line `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0'` in the *app/build.gradle*

```
dependencies {
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0'  //if I comment out this line the app compiles and builds normally. 
//Also I can use FirebaseAuth in the app so I don't think I have wrongly configured Firebase
}
```

Gradlew logs

```
      Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' into context took 0.0 secs.
file or directory 'C:\Users\rober\OneDrive\Documents\VS\appname\android\app\src\debug\java', not found
Skipping task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' as it is up-to-date (took 0.117 secs).

:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 0.136 secs.
:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug' as it is up-to-date (took 0.162 secs).

:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 0.162 secs.
:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 7,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug' into context took 0.0 secs.
Executing task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug' (up-to-date check took 0.077 secs) due to:
  Task has failed previously.
All input files are considered out-of-date for incremental task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 7,5,main]) completed. Took 1.029 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.
```

I have even tried running it in Android studio and still nothing. Adding other dependencies like `cloud storage` and `cloud messaging` and the app builds normally. But after adding the `firestore` line, the error appears

Comment: I have added the `flutter run -v` logs

Comment: How exactly do I do that, the `--info` part

Comment: You can just run the part that causes the failure isolated: `projectDir/android/gradlew transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug --info`. The appended `--info`, which `flutter run` does not use, will show you the actual DexMerger error.

Comment: when i run this it opens `cmd` and starts running on completion. `cmd` just exits without giving time to read the result. So i run the command in the `cmd` directly and the result i have posted but am not sure it is the error exactly

Comment: no. Found what i was doing wrong. Check log updates

Comment: I did not mean i solved the question. Do you have any suggestions. I have even added `realtime database`, `cloud messaging`, those dependencies i think i will need in future and they don't affect anything. On adding the `firestore` dependency, everything stops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found an answer in another post on Stackoverflow still
These lines of code should be added in build.gradle file (Module: app).

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Comment: That is what I suspected firstly, but the updates of your posts did not help me in that regard.

Comment: it would also work without adding `multiDexEnabled = true` if you change the firestore version to `16.0.0`